# How to change Report Viewer settings when report changes in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, report-viewer2012

I have a report viewer that I use to display multiple reports. So the user basically selects a report he wants to see and I display it on the report viewer. While the form that holds the report viewer is open the user can select a different report and I can display it, no problem. The issue arises when the user first chooses a report that is in landscape mode and without closing the report viewer form chooses a report that is in portrait mode. The portrait form report displays in landscape mode because the initial report displayed was in landscape mode and vise versa.

So I guess I need a way to initialize the report viewer each time a new report is being displayed so that it takes the mode of the new report. Or set the display mode of the report viewer to the correct mode of the report depending on the mode of the report being called for display.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Found it...

```
ReportViewer1.ResetPageSettings()
```

Thanks